# How to compare String received from servlet in android?

Tags: android, http, servlets, server, httpresponse

In my android application i need to check the string returned from java servlet and make textview change accordingly.

```
if(stat.equalsIgnoreCase("open")) {
    tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tx.setText("getting");
}
else {
    tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tx.setText("not getting");
}
```

Where "stat" is the string returned from server. Though the value of variable stat is "open" the control goes into the else part.Also stat.length() returns 6 when actual length is 4. Here is how i am receiving my response from the servlet.

```
final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
stat = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Can someone explain where am i going wrong?

Comment: Maybe there are some whitespaces involved

Comment: "_stat.length() returns 6 when actual length is 4_" Java is not lying to you about this. It may LOOK like only 4 characters, but if the length is 6, then there are 6 characters. They might be whitespace, they might be before the string, they might be after, but they are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "trim" the return value.

Example :

```
if(stat.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("open"))
    {
        tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tx.setText("getting");
    }
else {
        tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tx.setText("not getting");
    }
```